# How to cross-build luajit-5.1 for an ARM Linux device? (Trying to build LÖVE framework)

Tags: arm, love2d, luajit, cross-build

I'm trying to cross-build LÖVE (https://love2d.org) for an ARM Linux device (Rockchip RK3066) from Ubuntu 16.04.

As the documentation says, I installed all dependencies on Ubuntu and was able to build it (for Ubuntu, as a test). Now I'm going for the cross-build.

Before building, I have to run ./configure. So far I've been able to get the toolchain's gcc compiler to be accepted, but when it looks for the dependencies, I get this error:

```
checking for luajit5.1... no
checking for luajit51... no
checking for luajit... no
configure: error: Package requirements (luajit) were not met:

No package 'luajit' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables lua_CFLAGS
and lua_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Could this be fixed by cross-building luajit for the device and add it to the toolchain binaries, or could I just try to make the ./configure script look for the luajit I installed in Ubuntu?

If it's the latter, would someone kindly point me on the right direction? I've opened like 20 pages already with a similar error message and none of them had a valid answer.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: stackoverflow still has the site https://askubuntu.com/ too, perhaps try there if you never get a satisfying answer here.

Comment: Will try. Thank you!